# How to fix whenever I click on a page link within site, I get logged out?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, security, session

I have an intranet site with multiple page links linking to other pages within the site on each page. The issue is that if I login to my profile for example I have no problem, but if I click on a link to say my index page or recent news page or whatever it takes me to the page but I get logged out and I have to login again. I've found out that linking between pages out works if the user's password is "something"

I have two versions of this site, the only difference is that they connect to different databases. On one domain everything works fine, on the other is when I get this issue.

This is at the top of every page for connections to the database and checking to see if the user has the right credentials and just some functions. I think the issue should be with the code checking the user credentials and or starting the session.

```
<?php

    // Connect To Secure Login
    $cfgProgDir = 'phpSecurePages/';
    include($cfgProgDir . "secure.php");
    //These are the includes needed to make the php page run
    // this file connects to the database
    include("includes/connect.inc.php");
    // This file holds all the custom functions
    include("includes/functions.inc.php");
```

This is the config file

```
$cfgIndexpage = '/index.php';

    $cfgServerHost = '********************';             // MySQL hostname
    $cfgServerPort = '';                      // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
    $cfgServerUser = '*********';                  // MySQL user
    $cfgServerPassword = '**********';                  // MySQL password

    $cfgDbDatabase = '******';        // MySQL database name containing phpSecurePages table
    $cfgDbTableUsers = 'members';         // MySQL table name containing phpSecurePages user fields
    $cfgDbLoginfield = 'firstName';                // MySQL field name containing login word
    $cfgDbPasswordfield = 'password';         // MySQL field name containing password
    $cfgDbUserLevelfield = 'permission';       // MySQL field name containing user level
      // Choose a number which represents the category of this users authorization level.
      // Leave empty if authorization levels are not used.
    $cfgDbUserIDfield = 'id';        // MySQL field name containing user


    /****** Data ******/
    /* this data is necessary if no database is used */
    $cfgLogin[1] = '';                        // login word (username)
    $cfgPassword[1] = '';                     // password
    $cfgUserLevel[1] = '0';                    // user level
```

and the connect file ($connect) just connects the my DB

Any suggestions on what the issue could be?  :)

Comment: Tags don't go in titles, the site handles that for you.

Comment: Also probably worth a read: [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](/help/mcve)

Comment: I took out the extra session and nothing changed. I am also using php 5 for both domains. I know now that unless the password equal "something" i get this issue. The "something" was the first password I set.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means your session is getting destroyed somewhere or cookies aren't being set.

I didn't dwelve much into the code (It's a bit messy) but... `secure.php` include `checklogin.php` on line 67. On `checklogin.php` file, Line 37, `session_start()` is called and it is called again on your config file.

It should raise a warning so, if you haven't seen it, you're either using an old version of PHP or you don't have error reporting enabled.

You should enable error reporting and check for any notice or warning.